# Not able to group few groups , commonly for all test in testng.xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

I am trying to group few groups in testng.xml , but i want to declare it commonly for all test tag's under suite,when i run testng.xml as TestNG Suite, non of the test ran

- tried removing "define" tag from "groups" tag, then i am able to run
  @Test's
- did not removed the define tag with name="all" , but not used
  it in run tag,

  then also, i am able to run @Test's

  ```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  <suite name="TestNgPractise">
  <groups>
  <define name="all">
  <include name="smoke"/>
  <include name="sanity"/>
  <include name="regression"/>
  </define>
  <run>
  <include name="all"/>     
  </run>
  </groups>
  <test thread-count="5" name="GroupingTest-PreloginPage">
  <classes>
  <class name="com.qa.tests.PreloginPageTest"/>
  </classes>
  </test>  
  <test thread-count="5" name="GroupingTest-LoginPage">
  <classes>
  <class name="com.qa.tests.LoginPageTest"/>
  </classes>
  </test> 
  </suite> <!-- TestNgPractise -->
  ```

Expected:
When I mention  commonly for all  as i have mentioned in my testng.xml,  i want all @Test's to be executed

Actual:
Non of the @Test's are executing

O/P in Eclipse:
[image]

*PreLoginPageTest.java*

```
public class PreloginPageTest {
@Test(groups={"sanity"})
public void preloginPageTest(){
    System.out.println("PreloginPageTest");
}
@Test(groups={"sanity","regression"})
public void validateLogo(){
    System.out.println("Logo present");
}
@Test(groups={"sanity","regression"})
public void validateUrl(){
    System.out.println("Correct URL present");
}
@Test(groups={"sanity","regression"})
public void validateTabs(){
    System.out.println("all four tabs present");
}
@Test(groups="sanity")
public void validateHeaderFooter(){
    System.out.println("Header Footer Present");
}
}
```

*LoginPageTest.java*

```
 public class LoginPageTest {

    @Test(groups={"sanity"})
    public void loginPageTest(){
        System.out.println("LoginPageTest");
    }


    @Test(groups={"regression"})
    public void valiadteUsernameField(){
        System.out.println("User name field present");
    }

    @Test(groups={"regression"})
    public void valiadtePasswordField(){
        System.out.println("Password field present");
    }

    @Test(groups={"regression"})
    public void validateLoginBUttonField(){
        System.out.println("Login button present");
    }

    @Test(groups={"smoke"})
    public void validateForgetPassowrdField(){
        System.out.println("forgot passowrd field present");
    }

    @Test(groups={"smoke"})
    public void validateRememberPasswordChrckboxField(){
        System.out.println("Remember passowrd checkbox present");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This `testng.xml` is working fine for me for both tests. The group return at suite level is applied to both tests and `smoke` group from both test classes are run

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite" thread-count="5" group-by-instances="false" verbose="1" allow-return-values="false" parallel="false" data-provider-thread-count="10" junit="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">

<method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
      <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
        groups.containsKey("smoke") ;
        ]]>
        </script>
     </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>

<test verbose="2"  name="GroupingTest-PreloginPage">

<classes>
                <class name="firsttestngpackage.PreloginPageTest">

             </class>
        </classes>
</test>  
<test verbose="2"  name="GroupingTest-LoginPage">
<classes>
                <class name="firsttestngpackage.LoginPageTest">

             </class>
        </classes>
</test> 

</suite>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but, this is not i want, my scenario is that , when i have 2 different test tags, then i wan to mention group tag only once , commonly for all my test tags

Comment: It is the second case in above answer where I mentioned test from all classes

Comment: But, it have only one test tag, where as my testng.xml have 2 test tags

Comment: share your classes for more info

Comment: please find the class info as added to the actual question